# How to open a servlet in Jquerymobile?

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine, servlets, jquery-mobile

I have a form page coded in jquery mobile. On the server I have my servlet on google app engine. I want to proceed the data written in the forms.

How to do that? Is there something like action in JQM or is there a good best practice?

Comment: Google for "jquery mobile submit form", and click on the first result link. It leads you to the documentation explaining how to submit a form: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/forms-sample.html

Comment: so the typical way would be to use the action="" for the button! BUT what if I am writing a chat application and get data from the server and have to show them?